# Google App Engine - JDO - How to update collection?

Tags: java, debugging, google-app-engine

I have an issue while trying to update one object in a collection,
using JDO.

Here are the facts:

- I have a class (let's call it
  BigClass), that has an embedded
  class(SmallClass) containing an
  ArrayList.
- I DONT use/need a transaction.
- I query the database to get a List of
  BigClass items that should be
  modified. I iterate through each of
  them.
- I remove an element from the list in
  the SmallClass embedded in the
  current BigClass, the changes are not
  ALWAYS persisted.
- If I print (log) the object after the
  change, it looks modified, but if i
  check the DataViewer, the object was
  not updated.
- I even tried using
  JDOHelper.makeDirty on the BigClass,
  with the fieldName SmallClass, and it
  still doesn't work.

Some relevant code:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(BigClass.class,"id==:ids");
List<BigClass> participatingUsers=(List<BigClass>)
q.execute(participantIDs);

//Update the participants
ListIterator<BigClass> it=participatingUsers.listIterator();
BigClass participant;
boolean modified;
while(it.hasNext())
{
    participant=it.next();
    participant.list.remove(smth);

    JDOHelper.makeDirty(participant,"collection");
}
....
modify other objects
....
pm.close()
```

Another thing is that some of the changes I make after this part are
persisted...

So, if you have any suggestions, shoot pls!

Cosmin

Comment: I would make sure to call pm.makePersistent(participant) right after you finished the modifications

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. In the same session I actually delete elements from 3 lists. And only in the last one the changes are always persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to call `pm.makePersistent(participant);` to persist your changes after you removed `smth` from `list`.